# How to change QSlider's background color

Tags: qt, background, qtwidgets, qslider, qpalette

I would like to change a slider's background color, but this code does not work:

```cpp
QPalette p( ui->verticalScrollBar->palette());
p.setColor( QPalette::Window, Qt::red );
ui->verticalScrollBar->setPalette(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the stylesheet on the Qt controls.  This should set the background color to red.

```
ui->verticalScrollBar->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal {background-color:red;}");
```

Answer is also here:

[QSlider handle is being hidden when changing the background of the groove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761599/qslider-handle-is-being-hidden-when-changing-the-background-of-the-groove)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Qt documentation, they have an example on customising a QSlider: [Qt Style Sheets Examples — Customzing QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider).

Changing the `background` property of the CSS class `QSlider::groove` should do the trick.