# QSlider handle is being hidden when changing the background of the groove

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, qslider

I'm trying to change the background image of the groove, and set an image on the handle.

While doing so, I ran into a situation where the handle (which works) is being covered by the groove the moment that I set the background to anything.

This simple example shows the issue when I change just the color and nothing else. The groove covers the handle with this bit of code. (user cannot slide now) I'm missing something critical.  What am I missing?

```cpp
mySlider = new QSlider(centralWidget);
mySlider->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("mySlider"));
mySlider->setGeometry(QRect(960, 500, 100, 25));
mySlider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
mySlider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal {background-color:yellow;}");
```

Here's what the slider looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, it seems that the handle is resized to a size that makes it invisible, but if it can move with some difficulty. The last statement I checked with the following code.

```
 connect(mySlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, [=](int value){
     qDebug()<<value;
 });
```

It is advisable to place a width and height, by example:

```
mySlider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal {background-color:yellow;}"
                        "QSlider::handle:horizontal {background-color:blue; height:16px; width: 16px;}");
```

[image]